# Unable to send array/object to intercom as cutom_attribute

Tags: php, intercom

I want to send an array/object to the intercom as custom_attribute, but it shows an error of `[code] => nested_custom_attributes [message] => Cannot submit an object as a custom attribute value )`.

Code sample:

```
    "custom_attributes" => [
         "payment_methods" => [
         "paypal" => false,
         "stripe" => false,
         "payoneer" => false
         ], 
    ]
```

Comment: have you thought of serializing?

Comment: `Cannot submit an object` You have no objects in your custom attribute. Is this your actual code?

Comment: How can I add an object to custom attribute? It is the actual code. @AlexHowansky

Comment: @SamMumm It is json_encoded before sending.

Comment: Ah ok then it appears it's just a poorly worded error message from Intercom. (Because you have an array, not an object.)